# Function with countifs and search text in cells

Tags: vba

I hope somebody can help, I have been stuck on this for days.

In my excel sheet I have a list of errors (not related to excel) which I want to count in a function. The problem is that some type of errors contains a unique reference which makes the countifs function in excel insufficient.

There are 4 column ranges I want to search in and 4 criteria’s (`ConigneeIdRange`, `ConsigneeId`, `ErrorMessageRange`, `ErrorMessage`, `DateRange1`, `Date1`, `DateRange2`, `Date2`). For most errors the countifs function is sufficient, because there is no unique reference in the cell (string), but I have 2 type of error messages that contains a unique value (shipment number). The first one contains the text “Unable” and the second contains the word “modified” in the string.

I have a list of 2000 rows and would like to know how many times a type of error occurred in a cell in each row within a specific month.

Perhaps a loop could be the solution? I don’t know how to add more criteria’s to below code and how to search within a string for the 2 type of errors.

```
Option Explicit
Function CErrorCountLoop(ByVal ConsigneeIdRange As Variant, ByVal ConsigneeId As Variant)

    Dim vItem As Variant
    Dim iCount As Integer

    iCount = 0

    For Each vItem In ConsigneeIdRange

        If vItem = ConsigneeId Then
            iCount = iCount + 1
        End If
    Next vItem

    CErrorCountLoop = iCount

End Function
```

See below the sample data:

1. Date    Error Message                       Consignee ID Result Desired
2. 43101   Invalid input                        7777778     2      3
3. 43103   Invalid input                        7777778     2      3
4. 43151   Invalid input                        7777778     2      0
5. 43131   Unable to process 445376             7777775     2      2
6. 43104   Modified by another process 445378   7777774     2      2
7. 43115   Unable to process 445380             7777775     2      2
8. 43119   Modified by another process 445390   7777774     2      2
9. 43120   Invalid input                        7777779     1      1
10. 43101   Invalid input                        7777778     2      3

Formula used: =COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$9,C2,$B$2:$B$9, IF(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("Modified",B2))),"*Modified*",IF(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("Unable",B2))),"*Unable*",B2)),$A$2:$A$9,">="&DATE(2018,1,1),$A$2:$A$9,"<="&DATE(2018,1,31))

In above formula the wildcards are removed after saving the post, but they are in the formula I used.

As you can see I didn't get the desired result. Can somebody help me to create a function which produce the desired results?

Comment: A screenshot or sample data would be very helpful here. Did you try using wildcards with your `COUNTIFS`?

Comment: Couldn't you use wildcards to ignore the unique reference?  E.g. `=COUNTIF(A3:A6,"*Unable*")`  _Edit:_ Sorry @BigBen... should've read your comment first, but I'll say it again.... _Wildcards!_

Comment: The countifs formula That works for most errors is as follow =countifs(K2:K2000, K2, H2:H2000, H2, B2:B2000, “>=“&date(2018,01,01), B2:B2000,”<=“&date(2018,01,31)). The Column K represents the consigneeId and Column H the Error message. If I use the wildcard it will not retrieve the desired results. I just want VBA to search for the text in the string when the result is 0. Hope its this helps to understand my issue. If not please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem, you can use wildcards within your `COUNTIFS`, first checking whether `H2` contains the text "Modified" or "Unable". If so, the fourth argument of `COUNTIFS` will use wildcards, otherwise it will just be `H2`.

```
=COUNTIFS(K2:K2000, K2, H2:H2000, IF(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("Modified",H2))),"*Modified*",IF(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("Unable",H2))),"*Unable*",H2)), B2:B2000, ">="&DATE(2018,1,1), B2:B2000,"<="&DATE(2018,1,31))
```

---

**EDIT 1**

[image]

This screenshot is my understanding of the data/formula you provided, with some revisions and comments as to why your results do not match the desired result. This is the revised formula I am using.

```
=COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$10,C2,$B$2:$B$10, IF(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("Modified",B2))),"Modified*",IF(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("Unable",B2))),"Unable*",B2)),$A$2:$A$10,">="&DATE(2018,1,1),$A$2:$A$10,"<="&DATE(2018,1,31))
```

1. Just to check, it looks like your data runs from `C2:C10`, but your formula only references `C2:C9`(?)
2. The `COUNTIFS` with wildcards is returning the correct results on the lines with "Unable" or "Modified"
3. On line 4, how is the desired result 0? The result is 3 currently because there are 3 lines (2, 3, and 10) that fit the criteria of your `COUNTIFS` - i.e. they all fall within January 2018. If you only want the count to display on rows that fall in January, you can test that condition first - maybe using something like this.

*Modified formula:*

```
=IF(AND(A2>=DATE(2018,1,1),A2<=DATE(2018,1,31)),COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$10,C2,$B$2:$B$10, IF(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("Modified",B2))),"Modified*",IF(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("Unable",B2))),"Unable*",B2)),$A$2:$A$10,">="&DATE(2018,1,1),$A$2:$A$10,"<="&DATE(2018,1,31)),0)
```

Comment: Date Error Message                  Consignee R  D
01-01-18 Invalid input                          7777778    2 3
03-01-18 Invalid input                          7777778    2 3
20-02-18 Invalid input                          7777778    2 0
31-01-18 Unable to process 445376  7777775    2 2
04-01-18 Modified by shipment 445378  7777774    2 2
15-01-18 Unable to process 445380  7777775    2 2
19-01-18 Modified by shipment 445390  7777774    2 2
20-01-18 Invalid input                          7777779    1 1
01-01-18 Invalid input                          7777778    2 3

Comment: Sorry my post above is a bit messy. I used the following formula and didn't get the desired result. =COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$9,C5,$B$2:$B$9, IF(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("Modified",B5))),"*Modified*",IF(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("Unable",B5))),"*Unable*",B5)),$A$2:$A$9,">="&DATE(2018,1,1),$A$2:$A$9,"<="&DATE(2018,1,31)). Under R there are my results from the formula and under D the desired results.

Comment: I have edited my question with sample data. Can somebody please help me in finding a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for my issue.

Option Explicit
Function CErrorCount(ConsigneeIdRange As Range, ConsigneeId As Long, ErrorMessageRange As Range, ErrorMessage As String, _
                        Date1Range As Range, Date1 As String, Date2Range As Range, Date2 As String) As Integer

'Counts the type of errors between dates

```
If InStr(1, ErrorMessage, "Unable", 1) Then
    CErrorCount = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(ConsigneeIdRange, ConsigneeId, ErrorMessageRange, "*Unable*", Date1Range, Date1, Date2Range, Date2)
ElseIf InStr(1, ErrorMessage, "modified", 1) Then
    CErrorCount = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(ConsigneeIdRange, ConsigneeId, ErrorMessageRange, "*modified*", Date1Range, Date1, Date2Range, Date2)
Else
    CErrorCount = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(ConsigneeIdRange, ConsigneeId, ErrorMessageRange, ErrorMessage, Date1Range, Date1, Date2Range, Date2)

    End If
```

End Function